# Changing Frames

Tags: frames, gears, shocks

I just had a crash and wrecked my Cube hardtail mountain bike. Can I put all the parts, wheels, Reba Rock Shock, Shimano gears etc off my hard tail on to a full suspension frame?

Answer (score 2):

Depends. First, you need to know the parts are still good. Then, you just need to match the frame's compatibilities. Are the wheel sizes the same and do they have the same width hubs? (The second answer is almost surely yes). Do you have mounts for the same type or appropriate brakes on both bikes to match the wheels? Does the new frame have a compatible headset and is rated for the appropriate amount of travel? Similar questions will be asked for each component, like if the front derailleur mount is the same between bikes.

You can likely move a lot of components off if they're good, but each of the components is on a case by case basis.

Comment: Hub compatibility is about more than width. There is 135mm QR, and then there are thru-axle designs at 135x10, 142x12, 150x12, 157x12...

Comment: Good point, though some frame makers have conversion kits between some of them.